Decoding of 1-wire communication with the boiler controller
I need support in decoding the communication of the boiler controller.
I set as a goal to extend a simple controller with my own design. Unfortunately, I have fallen on a rather simple issue and have run out of ideas.
The controller is built on an Atmega8 and has a factory port for remote control via rj11 cable and I want to use this port.
What I have determined:
4 wires

data signal
High 5v (no signals)
low (no signals)
12v (excluded)

The original remote control does not have its own power supply so I figured that the 12v line is only for power. The High and Low lines can be shorted to simulate the signal from the thermostat that the set temperature has been reached.
Thus, I am left with 1 wire for communication, and the data appears on it. And here I lost.
The logic analyzer set to decode the 1-wired protocol does not give correct results.

My goal for the moment is to read the temperature readings. But I have not been able to extract anything of value from reading the logic states.

If this is valid data at all, then that's not a binary encoded protocol but maybe pulse width based somehow.

Exactly, even if it is a protocol sent over one wire, it does not mean it's the 1-Wire protocol.

ok, my mistake I didn't add that I figured out that it's not a 1-wire protocol but still communication is bi-directional over 1 wire. I put up the post hoping that someone has the knowledge to help decipher this signal waveform.
I don't understand why you are suggesting that the data is incorrect. A similar or identical waveform appears every half second.
